# Java:Prepare resources(.png,.txt,.arff) to create a runnable Jar wtih Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources

I have a java project in Eclipse and I have a couple of .arff files+1 png file.

I want to compile my project and create a runnable jar.
The thing is I can't find the best solution so that the jar can run using arff files.
Right now I have a structure like that:

```
Nameofproject
|
|
-------src
|        |
|        testpackage
|                      |
|                      |
|                      test1.java
|
 -------resources
|              |
|              | 
|              abc.arff
|              logo.png
|              ...
```

Inside my code I call the required arff files using
inputReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(**getClass().getResource("/resources/abc.arff").getFile()**));

and for the png file:
logo= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/logo.png"));

Can you tell me what is the procedure to create a runnable jar which will be able to correctly read both arff and png files?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/abc.arff");
```

Or if resources is marked as a source folder in your IDE, then

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("abc.arff");
```

More info:

Check that you've designated resource as a source folder. When you build a jar, check where the resources are packaged within it. If they are in the root of the jar, it should be

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("abc.arff");
```

otherwise, it will be something like:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path/to/abc.arff");
```

Comment: Nope!It didn't work using eclipse!Will it work if I make a jar and try it?

Comment: It should do. When you make a jar, you can unzip it and check that the resources are packaged correctly. The getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/") references the root of the classpath (i.e. the root of your jar), so just build up a path to the resource, as it is packaged within your jar.

Comment: Hmm the method you mentioned returns a URL but afterwards I need to use a FileReader which required a string!What should I do to transform it to a string?

Comment: Forgot to emphasise, the resource folder should be marked as a source folder, unless it resides under an existing source folder. Otherwise, it will never be on the classpath, or packaged within the jar.

Comment: You can use getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() to get the input stream to the file directly.

Comment: When I unzip the jar I only get to see the src folder.I don't see any resources folder, unless I go inside src folder.How can I mark it as  a source folder?

Comment: Ok here is the deal:
My jar can see the image file if I use this command:
logo= new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sleep.png"));

But when I use the command below the jar can't find the correct file path:

inputReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/abc.arff").getFile()));

I unzipped my jar and everything(arff,png) now is in the top folder(the one I get immediately after unzipping)

Comment: All right, I think I gave you the wrong pointer... I'll update the original answer. The getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() method doesn't take a leading slash. It always starts at the root of the classpath. So inputReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("abc.arff").getFile())); should be ok given that you've confirmed that the abc.arff is packaged in the root of your jar.

Comment: Nope!Istill get null!
Maybe it is an eclipse's problem!
I just can't get a non-null return...